# What is the JavaScript Date Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, range

What is the JavaScript year Range in `Date()` object

i know in `MS SQL` year date range is for `datetime` data type is from 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31

and even in JavaScript month range is 0- 11 any thing else will be invalid date

i was testing this and here is some of the results :

```
new Date(99999,1,1) ; //is valid
```

But

```
new Date(1000000,1,1); // invalid
```

that means there is a year range right
any body knows what is it and why this exact range ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the date `new Date(99999,11,31,9999999)` is valid. It gives me Wed Oct 16 101140 15:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9):

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970
>   UTC. In time values leap seconds are ignored. It is assumed that there
>   are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day. ECMAScript Number values
>   can represent all integers from –9,007,199,254,740,992 to
>   9,007,199,254,740,992; this range suffices to measure times to
>   millisecond precision for any instant that is within approximately
>   285,616 years, either forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is
>   slightly smaller: exactly –100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days
>   measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970
>   UTC. This gives a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to
>   either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC

So if I say like:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(8640000000000000);
document.write(d);
```

Then it would output as:

**Fri Sep 12 275760 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**

But `d.setTime(8640000000000001);`

will not work

Answer (score 0):

You may also check this [reference](https://gist.github.com/mckamey/1265065) which gives the example as to what is the date range in Javascript.

Below is the code for reference:-

```
try{

module("ES5 ranges");

test("ES5 Epoch", function() {

    // epoch
    var expected = 0;
    var actual = new Date(expected);

    same(actual.getTime(), expected, "");
    same(actual.getUTCFullYear(), 1970, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMonth(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCDate(), 1, "");
    same(actual.getUTCHours(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMinutes(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCSeconds(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMilliseconds(), 0, "");
});

test("ES5 Min Date", function() {

    // epoch - 1e8 days
    var expected = -8.64e15;
    var actual = new Date(expected);

    same(actual.getTime(), expected, "");
    same(actual.getUTCFullYear(), -271821, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMonth(), 3, "");
    same(actual.getUTCDate(), 20, "");
    same(actual.getUTCHours(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMinutes(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCSeconds(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMilliseconds(), 0, "");
});

test("ES5 Max Date", function() {

    // epoch + 1e8 days
    var expected = 8.64e15;
    var actual = new Date(expected);

    same(actual.getTime(), expected, "");
    same(actual.getUTCFullYear(), 275760, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMonth(), 8, "");
    same(actual.getUTCDate(), 13, "");
    same(actual.getUTCHours(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMinutes(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCSeconds(), 0, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMilliseconds(), 0, "");
});

module("Overflow Date ranges");

test("Underflow Date", function() {

    // epoch - 1e8 days - 1 ms
    var expected = -8.64e15-1;
    var actual = new Date(expected);

    same(actual.getTime(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCFullYear(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMonth(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCDate(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCHours(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMinutes(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCSeconds(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMilliseconds(), NaN, "");
});

test("Overflow Date", function() {

    // epoch + 1e8 days + 1 ms
    var expected = 8.64e15+1;
    var actual = new Date(expected);

    same(actual.getTime(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCFullYear(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMonth(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCDate(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCHours(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMinutes(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCSeconds(), NaN, "");
    same(actual.getUTCMilliseconds(), NaN, "");
});


}catch(ex){alert(ex);}
```